# Multiple file inclusion to a single class conflict

Tags: c++, class, c-preprocessor, conflict

**Here is the setup of the problem:**

1. MainFile.c calls the file SubFileA.h and SubFileB.h
2. SubFileA.h needs to call the class SigleClass.h
3. SubFileB.h also needs to call the class SingleClass.h

**Here are the contents of the file.** 
MainFile.h contains the following lines:

```
#include "SubFileA.h"
#include "SubFileB.h"
...
```

SubFileA.h contains the following lines:

```
#include "SingleClass.h"
...
void InsertPendingRejectedTrx(SingleClass oLogic);
...
```

SubFileB.h contains the following lines:

```
#include "SingleClass.h"
...
void InsertPendingRejectedTrx(SingleClass oAnotherLogic); //line 52
...
```

The SingleClass.h file contains the following lines:

```
#ifndef SC_LOGIC
#define SC_LOGIC
...
[lots of codes]
...
#endif
```

**Here is the error Code:**

```
SubFileB.h: At global scope:
SubFileB.h:52: error: âSingleClassâ has not been declared
```

When I try to compile, the compiler returns an error. It says that from the SubFileB, the "SingleClass" was not included. How can I solve this problem?
Note: The codes already works before, but when I included the SingleClass from the SubFileB.h for some reasons, the compiler returned an error.

Comment: Does subfileB.h include SingleClass.h? Also please add details of which file includes which header.

Comment: Add exact error message.

Comment: Kirill, I added the error message.

Comment: I've recreated this situation, and I'm not getting an error message at all. Can you show us more about what the files are doing (especially at line 52, where the error is)?

Comment: I don't see why you're getting that error. Are you using any namespaces. I do worry you may be defining two functions with the exact same name and signature at global scope, the compiler won't be able to tell which is which if you try to call InsertPendingRejectedTrx from MainFile.cpp. I think you've missed showing us the code that's the actual cause of your problem. Can you try to remove unnecessary code, perhaps by temporarily commenting it out... or create a new small dummy project with just the code you think is causing the problem and try that.

Comment: Okay, thanks sir Scott Langham, maybe it's the best thing that I can do. Because the project is extremely large, that's why I'm having a hard time searching for the solution to this one. This is also what I suspect, but still I'm also seeking second thoughts from the "EXPERTS" :)

Comment: Does the project define namespaces? Could it be that SingleClass is defined in a namespace, and in SubFileA.h you are 'using' the namespace, but not in SubFileB.h?

Comment: I checked if the SingleClass is defined in a namespace, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need yo centralize your header files, create a header file and include your header files in your the given file.squid cache server uses same algorithm,Of course , you should #include directive with  priority, because they depend on together.